# Populate submodel dependent on model id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

first of all sorry if my title is incomprehensible. I'm still learning so please be forgiving. I searched StackOverflow but found nothing that I can clip into my problem. 
So... I'm teaching myself MVC and C# and I decided to create small Blog App. I'm using N-Tier architecture which contains Blog.Back(admin panel front-end stuff and controllers that are using ModelProviders from Logic to manipulate data), Blog.DAL which contains EDMX, Blog.Logic which contains Models and ModelProviders. I've got this model:

```
    public class CategoryModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List Posts { get; set; }

        public CategoryModel()
        {
            Posts = new List();
        }
    }
```

which contains constructor that inits empty Posts, but I can't figure out how to populate it with data and for now if I loop through my CategoryModel to list Categories and in my views if I count(@Model.Posts.Count()) it always returns 0. Any ideas? Please be detailed with answers.

Sorry if it is duplicate. I tried searching but found nothing similar.

Answer (score 0):

You must create an CategoryModel object and populate it with some data, e.g.:

```
var model = new CategoryModel
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Some Name",
    Posts = new List<Post>
    {
        new Post() {
            SomeProperty = "Some Property"
        },
        new Post() {
            SomeProperty = "Some Property"
        }
    }
};
```

Then you can loop through it its Posts property using this code:

```
foreach (var post in model.Posts)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Property: ", post.SomeProperty);
}
```

Maybe this is not a perfect example but I hope it will help you a little.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. I already have CategoryModel and PostModel, which reflects fields in database Category and Post, and I've got data in DB so If for example I have 3 posts that has category Sport I need to be able to count them without populating it outside of model. Before I switched to n-tier and repository pattern approach I didn't created Model, but I used properties from EDMX, and when I used @model.Posts.Count() and It worked fine, but now I feel that the model isn't filled.

Comment: Then I think that what you need to do is to query the database and return the total count of posts from category...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I should fill model in a method that map base model to my model, for me it was:

```
    public static CategoryModel From(Category data, bool deep = false)
    {
            return new CategoryModel()
            {
                Id = data.Id,
                Name = data.Name,
                Posts = data.Posts.Select(p => PostModel.From(p)).ToList()
            };
    }
```

But I fall into endless looo couse of PostModel calling CategoryModel and CategoryModel was calling PostModel. So I gave a second parameter "deep". And here it is. Count is working like a charm and model is populated.

```
    public static CategoryModel From(Category data, bool deep = false)
    {
        if (deep)
        {
            return new CategoryModel()
            {
                Id = data.Id,
                Name = data.Name,
                Posts = data.Posts.Select(p => PostModel.From(p)).ToList()
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new CategoryModel()
            {
                Id = data.Id,
                Name = data.Name
            };
        }
    }
```

It's working but is it correct?